# Synaptic Manager Error

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, skype

I recently downloaded Skype Beta which works fine but I have been getting an error while updating packages from Synaptic Manager:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list:1
```

NOTE: It hasn't been long since I switched to Linux so if someone can explain the error and provide some help, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: How, exactly, did you 'download' Skype beta? Details matter, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Skype repository is defined twice. Once in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list` and again in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list`. You should remove one of them... but which one? Do this...

In `terminal`...

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list
```

the output of the cat commands **may** be different. The first one will probably be for the Skype stable version, and the second one will be for the beta version of Skype. Review them carefully.

You'll want to **either**...

```
- delete the skype-stable.list file
- delete the skypeforlinux.list file
```

To do **one** of the above... do **either**...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list
```

## Update

It looks like Microsoft used two different repo .list names depending on when you installed Skype. The latest installer, skypeforlinux-64.deb actually lays down a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list file.

The /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list file came from a previous Skype install... so that's where you end up with two .list files, and causes all of the problems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56031/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-synaptic-manager-error).